# What is the meaning of 'but' in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, grammar, prepositions, conjunctions

What is the meaning of 'but' in this sentence?

> "Remember the lady who moved across the hall? So I get into the elevator today and who else gets in but her!"

What does the 'but' mean here, and how else could I express it using different wording?

Comment: "none other than"

Comment: Have you looked in a dictionary? It means 'except'.

Comment: "...and who else gets in but her" is a way of conveying that anybody in the world could've gotten into that elevator that day, but it wasn't anybody else; it was her.  The speaker is pointing out how unlikely it was that of all the people who could've gotten onto the elevator right then, it was her who got on.

Comment: @marcellothearcane What would "Who else gets in except her?" mean exactly?

Comment: @BenjaminHarman That sounds like a good answer masquerading as a comment!